# Grep in multiple files prints matches line with file name

Tags: printing, grep

I'm using grep to found matching lines from a file in two different files. It finds the matching files just fine from `File1` into `File2` and `File3`, but from the moment there is more than one file, it prints the file name in which it was found next to the line.

```
grep -w -f File1 File2 File3
```

Output:

`File2: pattern`

`File2: pattern`

`File3: pattern`

Is there an option to avoid the print of `File2:` and `File3:`?

Answer (score 5):

```
grep --no-filename -w -f File1 File2 File3
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're on a UNIX system, please refer to the man pages.  Whenever you encounter a problem, your first step should be `man $programName`.  In this case, `man grep`.  It appears that you want the "-h" option.  Here's an excerpt from the man page:

```
   -h, --no-filename
          Suppress the prefixing of file names on output.  This is the default when there is only one file (or only standard input) to search.
```